# Commas in BeautifulSoup csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to output some web scraped information to a csv.  When I print it to the screen it comes out as I expect but when I output to a csv it has commas between every character.  I'm being dumb,  but what am I missing?

Here's my relevant python code:

```
list_of_rows = []
for hotel in hotels:
    for row in hotel.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'listing_title'}):
        list_of_rows.append(row.find('a').text.replace('\nspb;', ''))

print(list_of_rows)
outfile = open("./hotels.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
outfile.close()
```

**EDIT: Added example output**

When printed, list_of_rows comes out like this:

> [u"130 Queen's Gate", u'Hotel 41', u'Egerton House Hotel', u'The
>   Milestone Hotel', u'The Beaumont', u'COMO The Halkin', u'Taj 51
>   Buckingham Gate Suites and Residences', u'The Montague on The
>   Gardens', u'The Goring', u'Haymarket Hotel', u'Amba Hotel Charing
>   Cross', u'Rosewood London', u'Covent Garden Hotel', u'The Connaught',
>   u'The Chesterfield Mayfair', u'The Montcalm London Marble Arch',
>   u'Corinthia Hotel London', u'The Soho Hotel', u'Four Seasons Hotel
>   London at Park Lane', u'The Nadler Soho', u'Charlotte Street Hotel',
>   u'The Ritz London', u'The Nadler Victoria', u'Bulgari Hotel, London',
>   u"Brown's Hotel", u'The Arch London', u'The Piccadilly London West
>   End', u'The Stafford London', u'Ham Yard Hotel', u'Sofitel London St
>   James', u'Staybridge Suites London - Vauxhall']

But when sent to a csv there is a comma between each letter/space.

Comment: Is `list_of_rows` a regular list or a nested list at the end?

Comment: Can you add an example of what `list_of_rows` contains?

Comment: I think a detailed example of `list_of_rows` would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should supply the data as a nested list, where each sublist represents a single row.

```
data_mod = [[item] for item in list_of_rows]

with open("./hotels.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data_mod:
        writer.writerow(row)

# With writerows() being equivalent to the for loop + writerow()
```